# Pandas retrieve value in one column(s) corresponding to the maximum value in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Relatively new Python scripter here with a quick question about Pandas and DataFrames. There may be an easier method in Python to do what I am doing (outside of Pandas), so I am open to any and all suggestions.

I have a large data-set (don't we all), with dozens of attributes and tens of thousands of entries. I have successfully opened it (.csv file) and removed the unnecessary columns for the exercise, as well as used pandas techniques I learned from other questions here to parry down the table to something I can use

As an example, I now have dataframe `df`, with three columns - A, B and C. I need to find the index of the max of A and then pull the values of B and C at that index. Based off research on the best method, it seemed that `idxmax` was the best option.

```
MaxIDX = df['A'].idxmax()
```

This gives me the correct answer, however when I try to then grab a value using `at` based on this variable, I am getting errors. I believe it is because `idxmax` produces a series, and not an integer output.

```
variable = df.at[MaxIDX, 'B']
```

So the question I have is kind of two part.

How do I convert the series to the proper input for `at`? And, is there an easier way to do this that I am completely missing? All I want to do is get the index of the max of column A, and then pull the values of Column B and C at that index.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a bunch! Cheers!

Note:
Using: Python 3.6.4 and Pandas 0.22.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))

df

          A         B         C
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863


df.A.idxmax()
1
```

What you claim fails, seems to work for me:

```
df.at[df.A.idxmax(), 'B']
1.8675579901499675
```

Although, based on your explanation, you may instead want `loc`, not `at`:

```
df.loc[df.A.idxmax(), ['B', 'C']]

B    1.867558
C   -0.977278
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Note: *You may want to check that your index does not contain duplicate entries. This is one possible reason for failure.*

Comment: Thank you. The compound statement even helps me clean this up a bit, really appreciate it.

The issue I am getting with the `at` is the TypeError: Only Integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.

Could this have anything to do with my dataframe going through a `groupby` prior (I have as_index set to false), or the type of data contained? I am a novice so I'm trying to think for myself as well as ask.

The `loc` does work, so thank you! Still, I would like to understand the type issue and not just accept an answer. I want to learn and not let everyone else do my work :)

Comment: @Densoto Hard to say, since it seems the problem is based on your data (which I don't have)...

Comment: Another possibility is that you're dealing with an older version of pandas, and so you may want to upgrade to the latest (0.22 now I believe). (`pip install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: No problems. Thank you for the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Densoto Though let me just take a moment to appreciate your desire to learn. Very commendable. Great moves, keep it up!